# How to set and handle HTTP response code

Tags: java, exception

have a class that handles Http requests for me. This class contains some methods like

```
public static String getServerResponseByHttpGet(String url){...}
public static String getServerResponseByHttpGet(String url, String token){...}
public static String getServerResponseByHttpPost(String url, token, List<NameValuePair> pairs){...}
```

I'm able to get connection code by using `httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();`

Since I need to handle different situations like if connection code is 401, 403, 04, 409, etc. then I want to throw this code and catch it in implementation class. Is it possible to do that. I have following class but have no idea how to modify it in order to send integer value.

```
public class MyHttpClientException extends Exception {

    public MyHttpClientException() {

    }

    public MyHttpClientException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public MyHttpClientException (Throwable cause) {
        super (cause);
    }

    public MyHttpClientException (String message, Throwable cause) {
        super (message, cause);
    }
}
```

Comment: put the error code into your session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Exception`s are like other classes, you can add whatever you want in the implementation.

So to really simplify things:

```
public class MyHttpClientException extends Exception {
    private final int errorCode;

    public MyHttpClientException(final int errorCode) {
         this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }

    // rest of the constructors, one example:
    public MyHttpClientException(int errorCode, String message) {
         super(message);
         this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }

    public int getErrorCode{
        return errorCode;
    }
}
```

Then where the error happens

```
throw new MyHttpClientException(errorCodeHere);
```

When you catch it:

```
try {
    // request
} catch (MyHttpClientException e) {
    int errorCode = e.getErrorCode();
    // do whatever you want with it.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like the Java RESTful service API's [`WebApplicationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html), you can add a `int` member to your `MyHttpClientException` and set it on the constructor:

```
public class MyHttpClientException extends Exception {

    private int code;

    public MyHttpClientException(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
.
.
.

    public int getCode(){
        return code;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When programmers get into touch with exceptions the first time, they always extend `Exception` and create all those constructors that this super class has.

But exceptions are also full-fledged objects that should be used as other objects, too. So the easiest way to declare such an exception is:

```
public final class MyHttpClientException extends Exception {

    private int final httpCode;

    public MyHttpClientException (int httpCode) {
        super(String.valueOf(httpCode));
        this.httpCode = httpCode;
    }

    public MyHttpClientException (int httpCode, Throwable cause) {
        super(String.valueOf(httpCode), cause);
        this.httpCode = httpCode;
    }

    public int httpCode() {
        return httpCode;
    }

}
```